# Adding my own custom template page but got white page

Tags: php, pages, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on a e-shop with WordPress and Woocommerce. I bought a template and i'm looking for create my own custom single page.

So i followed this [tutorial](http://www.ringabell.org/appeller-un-fichier-de-template-custom-avec-une-rewrite-rule-dans-wordpress/) but when i tried to acces to my page with this link `//www.mywebsite.com/retour-produit/5904` i got a white page.

I add my template here: `/public_html/wp-content/themes/child-laneluxury/woocommerce/myaccount`

```
//Ajouter le template du formulaire pour la demande de remboursement

add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'wc_return_refund_form_template', 10 , 2 );
function wc_return_refund_form_template($actions, $order){

global $woocommerce;
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();
$check_statut = get_user_meta($user_id, 'statut', true);

if($order->has_status( 'completed' ) && $check_statut == 'particulier'){
  //Si la date est dépassée par rapport aux options
  $last_day = (get_option( 'wc_return_days' ) == '') ? '' : date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order->post->post_date . ' + '. get_option( 'wc_return_days' ) .' days'));
  if ( ($last_day != '') && ($last_day < date("Y-m-d")) ){
  }
  else{
      $actions['name'] = array(
        'url'  => '/retour-produit/'.$order->get_order_number(),
        'name' => 'Retour produit(s)',
      );
  }
}
return $actions;
}

/*Custom route for customer refund form*/
function add_custom_refund_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('retour-produit/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?custompage_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_refund_rewrite_rules' );

add_filter('query_vars', 'handle_custompage_query_vars');
function handle_custompage_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'custompage_var';
    return $query_vars;
}

//Template
add_filter('template_include', 'my_template', 1, 1);
function my_template($template)
{
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['custompage_var'])) {
    return child_template_directory.'/woocommerce/myaccount/retour-produit.php';
}
return $template;
```

Comment: what is your php error level set to ?

Comment: I just set my wp-config with that "define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );" Well i dont really know what it cannot get my template because when i desactive the filter "add_filter('template_include', 'my_template', 1, 1);" It just load a default template for product.

Comment: Are you copy this code 1:1? You missing last bracket to close. Look in php_error.log on your root or i cPanel where is error also.

Comment: Not i didnt copy this code 1:1. I did something by my own first but got the same error and now trying to follow this tutorial but still dont understand why i cannot get any error and only a white page.
When i try to modify the location of my template it said that the server cannot find my template but when it load it i got white page.

Comment: Can you see the source of that blank page? Is it also blank?

Comment: Yes it's blank, no error on the console. That's why it's hard for me to debug

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to do a template override in Woocommerce.

If by single you mean a page when viewing only one product then look at the single-product.php template.

The directory it needs to located is: /public_html/wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/single-product.php.

You can download the template overrides from woothemes.

Comment: I want to create my own dynamic page like "www.mysite.com/refund-product/id_product" because i want my customer to be able to refund the products. That's why i wanna write my own template with my own url_rewrite